# How to prolong battery life

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have recently brought my self a MacBook Pro (2015) battery life because I was getting 4 hours or less on my MacBook Air (2010) that had about 800-880 cycle counts. Because of the battery issue with my MacBook Air I would like to know how to extend the battery life.

Is there a way how I can make sure my battery lasts for more then 4 years while staying close to 10 hours?

#### Here are a few things that I know about looking after batteries:

- Cycle counts (1 cycle count is 50% to 100% back to 50% etc.)
- It is best to keep your battery between 20% and 80% (is it true?)

#### What I want to know more of:

- More information on how cycle counts work (not sure if I fully understand them)
- How to reduce number of cycle counts (less is better)
- What is the battery life of an average use with 60% battery (between 20% and 80%) (need to last at least for 8+ hours without charging)
- Any applications that prevents the computer being charged over 80% (if possible)
- Any other tips for extending battery life

#### My end goal:

- I want to have good battery life (~10 hours) all the time and at least 8 (or as much as possible) hours in four years time (or 800+ cycles [which ever comes first]).

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Here is a place you can learn all about Batteries.

[Battery University](http://batteryuniversity.com/).

and from Apple [here](https://www.apple.com/batteries/)

To you question on 8+ hour, the new MacBook Air (2104 model) has that.

> The 11-inch MacBook Air lasts up to 9 hours between charges and the
>   13-inch model lasts up to an incredible 12 hours.

The cycle count is only one of the indicator and can not be used as absolute measure of Battery status. You need to look at the Full Charged Capacity (in About This Mac- Power)to get total understanding of the battery status. That one indicates the capability of the battery to hold the charge indicating how many cells are not doing so well and not holding the charge.

With all that said, if you use the battery in the Apple prescribed manner, you can not prolog its life beyond the original design, or beyond the physics and chemistry involved. For example a battery will develop short circuits due to build up of Whiskers (growth of Li metal deposits) that short out portions of the cells during its life and there is not much you can do about that.

Comment: I have a MacBook Pro and the 8+ hour was keeping it charged between 20% charge to 80% charge. Not sure if we are getting each other. Thanks for helping though. Also do you mean 2014? :)

Comment: You have to many questions in one. I tried to give you sources where to get answers. Basic rule, keep it cool (heat is killer). Always use power cord when possible. Do not let it discharge completely.  A charge cycle means using all of the battery’s power, but that doesn’t necessarily mean a single charge. For instance, you could use your notebook for an hour or more one day, using half its charge, and then recharge it fully. If you did the same thing the next day, it would count as one charge cycle, not two, so it may take several days to complete a cycle.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Also with battery counts how many will this be? Say if my computer was at 50% and I charged it up to 100%. I then discharged it to 75% and charged it to 100%. How many cycle counts will this be?

Comment: That would result in no charging counts. The best indicator of remaining battery life is the amount of charge it can hold (mAh) compared to the original (new). Example FROM MY MBA (2012) Full Charge Capacity (mAh):4789, while the original was 8000mAH, So I am <1/2 of life with 622 cycles

Comment: Thanks for this. Think I have a bit more knowledge in the batteries now. :)